# SVG path cut-off by the container

Tags: javascript, css, svg

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoCio.png) is my SVG path

My CSS code as follows;

```
svg {
    width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
    background-color: #2a0800;
}

svg path{
    stroke-width: 20;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
    stroke: #ff682b;
}
```

The SVG path is cut by the borders of the square. How can I increase the size of this container/black-background dynamically so that that when I increase the stroke-width, I don't get this cut-off.

Comment: Adjust the viewbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Comment: @Paul I don't define the svg element in between `<svg>` tags, instead I have the svg object returned from a function, which belongs to a library. So, at this point, how can I use the viewbox?

Comment: Use an [SVG view](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG) to apply the viewBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting padding into the svg solved my problem;

```
svg {
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the svg's viewBox. Sometimes the padding does not working accordingly

Comment: CSS Tricks breaks down your options and what works best. https://css-tricks.com/tight-fitting-svg-shapes/